# Dynamically change RESTEasy service return type

Tags: java, annotations, resteasy

Am I able to change the value of @Produces annotation parameter in my RESTEasy services??
The task I'm given is to integrate multiple format reporting to an existing reporting system.
So changing the @Produces annotation parameter dynamically would help me a lot.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your method return a `Response` object and try something like this;

```
int status = 200;
String type = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;
String response = "<hello>world</hello>";
return Response.status(status).type(type).entity(response).build();
```

I think the type in the response will override what you annotated, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Yeap ... it overrides the annotated type.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify several entries in @Produces. Your request should mention which format (as mime type) do you want as the result.

Example:

```
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
```

Comment: Thanks Nanda! Seems to be a nice solution... how about PDF here??