# resteasy response

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat7

I have a similar case as the one described here: [Dynamically change RESTEasy service return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786781/dynamically-change-resteasy-service-return-type)

The problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to return a list of objects (annotated with `@XMLRootEntity`), but I get a 500 server error code:

> The server encountered an internal error (Could not find
>   MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of
>   media type: application/json) that prevented it from fulfilling this
>   request.

Can you give some advice how to solve this issue?

I'm not sure exactly where to look.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use interface instead of using implementation of list.

Try changing return type with : **java.util.List**

EDIT:
Try to wrap list into [GenericEntity](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) :

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
// add ...
final GenericEntity<List<String>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<String>>(myList) { };
Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(entity).build();
```

Comment: I am using list, but I guess it sees the implementation in the error stack. Before trying to return Response I tried returning List<MyObject> and everything worked ok. Problems appeared when trying to return a javax.ws.rs.Response object.

Comment: what's the return type of you're method ?

Comment: You can use a [ResponseBuilder](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) to create the Response.
The return type must be a javax.ws.rs.Response.

Ex: `Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(myList).build()`

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing now, but I get the error that I mentioned.

Comment: You probably couldn't imagine how much trouble your answer has saved me. Thanks!