# RestEasy: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/json

Tags: java, json, resteasy

> message: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type:
>   java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/json
>
> Description: The server encountered an internal error (Could not find
>   MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of
>   media type: application/json) that prevented it from fulfilling this
>   request

```
@GET
@Path("/{userName}/questions")
//@Produces("application/json")
public Response getUserQuestions(@PathParam("userName") String userName){               
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();        
    List<Question> questions = userDAO.getUserQuestionsByUserName(userName);        
    GenericEntity<List<Question>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Question>>(questions){};      
    return Response.status(200).entity(entity).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

I have got the resteasy jackson provider in the classpath.
Tried changing the return type form `ArrayList` to `List`, then wrapping it in `GenericEntity` based on [resteasy response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868722/resteasy-response), but still getting the same issue.

Running on tomcat7.

Thanks.

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618061/a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-java-util-arraylist-and-mime-media-type-t#answer-18240578) works perfect for me

Comment: The 3rd post in this thread worked for me using version 3.0.19:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365515/resteasy-could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-json-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally solved it using the `Gson library` instead of relying on json.
did not wrap in Generic Entity either. Here is the code that works

```
@GET
@Path("/{userName}/questions")
public Response getUserQuestions(@PathParam("userName") String userName){               
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();        
    List<Question> questions = userDAO.getQuestionsByUserName(userName);        
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new UserQuestionsExclStrat()).create(); //.serializeNulls()
    String json = gson.toJson(questions);
    System.out.println(json); 
    return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
}
```

Had to use the exclusion strategy to avoid cyclic reference. here is the link for that:[stackoverflow error during json conversion (hibernate bi-directional mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109098/stackoverflow-error-during-json-conversion-hibernate-bi-directional-mapping)

Answer (score 13):

I solved this exception by adding resteasy-jackson-provider.jar to classpath
Refer https://bitbucket.org/arcbees/gaestudio/issue/2/need-resteasy-jackson-provider-on

Comment: This worked for me . Thanks a lot . but why does it not work with jackson-mapper-asl.jar ?

Answer (score 5):

Faced same issue resolved by adding @XMLRootElement in class used in ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

By adding this dependency I was able to solve this issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```