# RESTEasy Could not find MessageBodyWriter - Jackson Configured

Tags: java, json, jackson, tomcat7, resteasy

I recently set up RESTEasy on Tomcat 7. We do not use Maven. I mention this early on, because all of the answers I've found to my question to date suggest adding a reference to the pom.xml. Adding references to my project, so far, hasn't solved my problem (but, maybe I'm missing something).

At this point, I'm just trying to recreate the out-of-the-box examples I've seen online where I should be able to correctly annotate a POJO, and return it as JSON using RESTEasy, assuming I have my build configured correctly. My build references:

```
 - jackson.core.asl
 - jackson.jaxrs
 - jackson.mapper.asl
```

and all the required RESTEasy jars. In fact, I can successfully obtain the JSON I want from a GET if I return a Response (as in the example I found here: [RestEasy: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089781/resteasy-could-not-find-messagebodywriter-for-response-object-of-type-java-uti)). Of course, that's not using Jackson through RESTEasy, at all.

Whenever I try to return an object, however, of any kind, I get:

- Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: ... application/json

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as all the answers I can find suggest that what I need to do is make sure that jackson is correctly referenced---which, from all I can tell, it is. Below is the relevant portion of my web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>rest_services.RootRestService</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/services</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Here is my Service method:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/getTables")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<MyTable> getTables() {
       ...
    }
```

Here is the class it's returning:

```
   @XmlRootElement
   public final class MyTable {

     ...

   }
```

**EDIT :**

Here are the classes I added to my classpath (and a few others)

[image: classpath]:

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you're using JAXB, you might additionally need the [Jackson JAXB module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Can you list all the jars from your application classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get Jackson working, but I switched to Jettison, and all works fine. This is good enough for me, for now.