# Dynamic result after error (List or Object)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

That's my first question, and I've researched but didnt find the answer...

I'm currently developing a REST Webservice using Resteasy. Its working fine but I've come to a doubt: there is a way to return a List OR a Object ?

Let me exemplify: I've got a method to return a LIST of SECTORS that is called after passing a token of authentication. 
If the token is OK - It should return the LIST of Sectors.
If the token is not OK - It should return an error which is mapped to a class called ErroGenerico that is an OBJECT.

How can I do that ? Return the OBJECT OR the LIST ?

Comment: make that object as an exception and catch it in calling code

Comment: Well, if you have and exception, you could use the result code and return the object. On the client, depending on the code, you will know if you have receive a `List` or an `Exception`.

Comment: You should not throw exception in cases where it can be done via other ways .As exception has to be used in condition which cannot be handled

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as below

```
//Not mandatory to create ListUser you can do without it oo just use arraylist directly
class ListUser extends ArrayList<User> {}
```

webservice method

```
@GET
@Path("getObj/{param}") 
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getObj(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

    ListUser responses = new ListUser();
    responses.add(new User("1"));
    responses.add(new User("2"));
    responses.add(new User("3")); 
    if("list".equals(msg))
        return Response.status(200).entity(responses).build();
    User u=new User();
    u.setName("Developer");
    return Response.status(200).entity(u).build();


}
```

Client code

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    {
        String url = "http://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/jws/getObj/list";
        System.out.println(url);
        Response response = client.target(url).request().get();
        ObjectMapper ob = new ObjectMapper();

        Object pojos = response.readEntity(Object.class);
        System.out.println(pojos.getClass());
         if(pojos instanceof java.util.ArrayList){
            ArrayList<User> list =  (ArrayList) pojos;

            for (Object pojo : list) {
                User user = ob.convertValue(pojo, User.class);
                System.out.println(user.getName());
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("user");
            User user = ob.convertValue(pojos, User.class);
        }
        //System.out.println(response);

    }
```

You can check working service at http://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/jws/getObj/list

Here instead of passing list you can pass anything else to get object

*In addition to this answer, I've found the article and it worked fine.*

[resteasy response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868722/resteasy-response)

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom exception `ErroGenerico` and throw it if the token is not verified.

so, method:

```
public List<Something> getList(String token) throw ErroGenerico {
// do stuff
}
```